# Qt - Simple code QPrinter doesn't work on others pc

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter, qprinter

```
QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);         

    printer.setPageSize(QPrinter::A4);
    printer.setOrientation(QPrinter::Portrait);
    printer.setPageMargins (15,15,15,15,QPrinter::Millimeter);
    printer.setFullPage(false);
    printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::NativeFormat);                     


    QPainter painter(&printer);                           

    painter.setFont(QFont("Tahoma",8));
    painter.drawText(200,200,"Test prova prova");
    painter.end();
```

In the PC with QT the print works right (print works normally), but in the others pc (one with win 8.1 and one with win 7) doesn't start (print doesn't start, the print queue is empty) I don't understand why and i don't get any error.

I use:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QPrinter>
#include <QPainter>
```

and in the .pro:

```
QT += printsupport
QTPLUGIN += windowsprintersupport
```

The dll "`Qt5PrintSupport`" is present inside the folder of course.
Sorry for the noob question but I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Do you get any errors? "Doesn't start" can mean anything.

Comment: Hi, no errors, simply i press the button "print" and the print doesn't start, the print queue is empty.

Comment: Your method is working on my machine (Windows 8). And how you are calling it?

Comment: Hi @demonplus, i calling it with a simple `void MainWindow::on_Stampa_clicked()
{}` a push button in the ui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the windowsprintersupport.dll plugin on the target machine. Setting QTPLUGIN does not work when you are using Qt as DLLs, only if statically linking Qt to your application.

Comment: Add `{myAppPath}\printsupport\windowsprintersupport.dll` and works perfect, thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a CMake project, you can use the Qt5::QWindowPrinterSupportPlugin to configure copying to the target directory.

`get_target_property(_loc Qt5::QWindowsPrinterSupportPlugin LOCATION)     configure_file(${_loc} Release/printsupport/windowsprintersupport.dll COPYONLY) message("copied file: ${_loc}")`